# Jquery List Items Draggable, Droppable, Merged and Removable

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need a Jquery plugin can be used to drag/drop/merged/removed from the list items.Is there any existing plugin or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Jquery IT](https://jqueryui.com/) can help you, please check it